# i'm trying to run this program in Python, but i'm not able to execute def

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to run this program in Python, but i'm not able to execute def. this is an assistant who shuold be able to catch words from the users and execute orders accordingly
the main question is:

1. how can I built an run more actions. example:
   user said: stevens, what do you think about sports?
   the IA (Steven) should be able to catch this string as an input order and execute a function and/or reply accordingly (based upon a pre-existing command line). Possible outputs should be: a. run a mp3 file, print a sentence, run a program
2. how can I execute def greeting?
   this is the whole code:

```
import gtts
from gtts import gTTS
import warnings
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import google
import random



warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


def record_audio():
   r = sr.Recognizer()
   global data

   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       print('Say something! ')
       audio = r.listen(source)


   try:
       data = r.recognize_google(audio)
       print(data)
   except sr.UnknownValueError:
       print('I am waiting for your orders')
   except sr.RequestError as e:
       print('Google speech rec error')
   return data

def assistant_responses(text):

   print(text)

   myobj = gTTS(text= text, lang= 'en', slow=False)

   myobj.save('assistant_response.mp3')

   os.system('start assistant_response.mp3')

def wake_words(text):

   WAKE_WORDS = ['stevens', 'hi stevens']

   text = text.lower()

   for phrase in WAKE_WORDS:
       if phrase in text:
           return True


   return False


def greeting(text):

   GREETING_INPUTS = ['hi', 'hey', 'hola', 'ciao', 'hello', 'good morning']
   GREETING_RESPONSES = ['hello sir', 'good morning sir', 'how can i help you sir?']

   for word in text.split():
       if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
           return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES) +'.'

   return ''


while True:
   text = record_audio()
   response = greeting(text)
   if wake_words(text) == True:
       print('Good day sir')
   elif greeting(text) == True:
       print('Hello sir')
```

Comment: Where do you want to execute the greeting?

Comment: Question 1 is a really open-ended question that's not suitable for StackOverflow, or at least it deserves its own question after being reworked (as long as it's allowed within the site rules). Question 2 isn't clear because you're already calling/executing `greeting`, i.e. in `response = greeting(text)`.

Comment: hello @RandomDavis maybe I misunderstood the whole process, but I would like the IA to response back to a specif greeting. e.g.= I write 'hello' he replied back ''hello sir', but that is not happening

Comment: @Enzo please explain what _is_ happening instead of what you want to have happen.

Comment: hello @tralph3 . when I say a greetings command I expect the IA to reply the greetings responses 'hello sir'. but it's not happening right now

Comment: @RandomDavis when i run the program, it record and write down my words (speech recognition is ok). If I say the greetings command it doesn't force a greetings responses back. whatever I say, the program write the words down and it asks me again: say something!

Comment: @itaishz Numbers greater than 0 and non empty strings return True in comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you want to have the result of `greeting` be displayed, but you're not displaying the result anywhere. This is how you currently call `greeting`:

```
response = greeting(text)
```

All this is doing is setting the variable `response` to something from `GREETING_RESPONSES`. It's not telling Python to display anything. You have to actually **print** the response (or do something else with it besides nothing):

```
response = greeting(text)
print(response)
```

Or just:

```
print(greeting(text))
```